# Lambda function with itertools count() and groupby()

Tags: python, lambda, python-itertools

Can someone please explain the groupby operation and the lambda function being used on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646148/fast-method-in-python-to-split-a-large-text-file-using-number-of-lines-as-input) SO post?

`key=lambda k, line=count(): next(line) // chunk`

```
import tempfile
from itertools import groupby, count

temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

def tempfile_split(filename, temp_dir, chunk=4000000):
    with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:

    # The itertools.groupby() function takes a sequence and a key function,
    # and returns an iterator that generates pairs.

    # Each pair contains the result of key_function(each item) and
    # another iterator containing all the items that shared that key result.

        groups = groupby(datafile, key=lambda k, line=count(): next(line) // chunk)
        for k, group in groups:

            print(key, list(group))

            output_name = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(temp_dir + os.sep, "tempfile_%s.tmp" % k))
            for line in group:
                with open(output_name, 'a') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

**Edit:** It took me a while to wrap my head around the lambda function used with groupby. I don't think I understood either of them very well.

Martijn explained it really well, however I have a follow up question. Why is `line=count()` passed as an argument to the lambda function every time? I tried assigning the variable `line` to `count()` just once, outside the function.

```
    line = count()
    groups = groupby(datafile, key=lambda k, line: next(line) // chunk)
```

and it resulted in `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'line'`

Also, calling `next` on `count()` directly within the lambda expression, resulted in all the lines in the input file getting bunched together i.e a single key was generated by the `groupby` function.

```
groups = groupby(datafile, key=lambda k: next(count()) // chunk)
```

I'm learning Python on my own, so any help or pointers to reference materials /PyCon talks are much appreciated. Anything really!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.count()` is an infinite iterator of increasing integer numbers.

The `lambda` stores an instance as a keyword argument, so every time the lambda is called the local variable `line` references that object. `next()` advances an iterator, retrieving the next value:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> line = count()
>>> next(line)
0
>>> next(line)
1
>>> next(line)
2
>>> next(line)
3
```

So `next(line)` retrieves the next count in the sequence, and divides that value by `chunk` (taking only the integer portion of the division). The `k` argument is ignored.

Because integer division is used, the result of the `lambda` is going to be `chunk` repeats of an increasing integer; if `chunk` is 3, then you get `0` three times, then `1` three times, then `2` three times, etc:

```
>>> chunk = 3
>>> l = lambda k, line=count(): next(line) // chunk
>>> [l('ignored') for _ in range(10)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> chunk = 4
>>> l = lambda k, line=count(): next(line) // chunk
>>> [l('ignored') for _ in range(10)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

It is this resulting value that `groupby()` groups the `datafile` iterable by, producing groups of `chunk` lines.

When looping over the `groupby()` results with `for k, group in groups:`, `k` is the number that the `lambda` produced and the results are grouped by; the `for` loop in the code ignores this. `group` is an iterable of lines from `datafile`, and will always contain `chunk` lines.

Comment: Thank You. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

In response to the updated OP...

The `itertools.groupby` iterator offers ways to group items together, giving more control when a key function is defined.  See more on [how `itertools.groupby()` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45873519/4531270).

The `lambda` function, is a functional, shorthand way of writing a regular function.  For example:

```
>>> keyfunc = lambda k, line=count(): next(line)
```

Is equivalent to this regular function:

```
>>> def keyfunc(k, line=count()):
...     return next(line) // chunk
```

*Keywords*: iterator, functional programming, anonymous functions

---

**Details**

> Why is `line=count()` passed as an argument to the lambda function every time?

The reason is the same for normal functions.  The `line` parameter by itself is a *positional argument*.  When a value is assigned, it becomes a default *keyword argument*.  See more on [positional vs. keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument).

You can still define `line=count()` outside the function by assigning the result to a keyword argument:

```
>>> chunk = 3
>>> line=count()
>>> keyfunc = lambda k, line=line: next(line) // chunk       # make `line` a keyword arg
>>> [keyfunc("") for _ in range(10)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
>>> [keyfunc("") for _ in range(10)]
[3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6]                               # note `count()` continues
```

> ... calling next on `count()` directly within the lambda expression, resulted in all the lines in the input file getting bunched together i.e a single key was generated by the `groupby` function ...

Try the following experiment with `count()`:

```
>>> numbers = count()
>>> next(numbers)
0
>>> next(numbers)
1
>>> next(numbers)
2
```

As expected, you will notice `next()` is yielding the next item from the `count()` iterator.  (A similar function is called iterating an iterator with a `for` loop).  What is unique here is that generators do not reset - `next()` simply gives the next item in the line (as seen in the former example).

@Martijn Pieters pointed out `next(line) // chunk` computes a floored integer that is used by `groupby` to identify each line (bunching similar lines with similar ids together), which is also expected.  See the references for more on how `groupby` works.

*References*

- [Docs for `itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count)
- [Docs for `itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
- Beazley, D. and Jones, B.  "7.7 Capturing Variables in Anonymous Functions," Python Cookbook, 3rd ed. O'Reilly. 2013.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!